# Searching giving "too many" results

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I found a product using a specific search in my store at #5 in the middle of my product grid. I'm using "Combined" for search. All but "Name" attribute is searchable....why is it #5 and not #1 on the top row?

Our site has really funky search results. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native MySQL search engine indexes all attributes you have configured to be indexed for search. On top of that, it runs an `OR` operation on matching words. So, you'll get all kinds of results if you let attributes like description be indexed.

This has some bullet points you might find useful: http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/5-tips-improving-on-site-search-results-using-magento-and-apache-solr/

Comment: I found one thing on that link useful. I used the search terms redirect to get some specific keywords to specific page.

Comment: Is there a way to change the `OR` operation to an `AND` operation?

Comment: @MichaelYaeger, I haven't looked at this in a while, but yes, you can do this if you overwrite some methods. I believe there were articles on how to do it on the Internet.

Comment: Is this directly related to the "Like" and "Fulltext" options in the "Catalog Search" settings?

Answer (score 1):

Simply because the internal search is terrible, the most accurate we have come across is Solr. There are other extensions but they, although better than internal, also have inconsistencies.